How to change Server Side rendered HTML before Client Side rendering on Quasar?
I am new to Vue.js. And I want to use Vue I18n. The problem is that when I set the locale on Vue I18n I need to set HTML lang attribute to the same locale but I can't access document on SSR mode. So, how can I change Server Side Rendered HTML before Client Side rendering?
  if (process.env.CLIENT) // This does not seem good hydration.
    document.querySelector('html').setAttribute('lang', i18n.global.locale.value)

I tried to solve the problem with Meta plugin but lang attribute is 'en-US'.
useMeta(() => ({
  htmlAttr: {
    lang: i18n.global.locale.value
  }
}))

I don't want to use Quasar Language Pack because it limits my locales as it does not allow me to use some region codes.
So, I decided to set the Quasar Lang configuration no html attrs to true:
// quasar.config.js
    framework: {
      config: {
        lang: {
          noHtmlAttrs: true // add this
        }
      },

Even so, lang attribute disappears from HTML tag.

See https://quasar.dev/quasar-plugins/meta/

I tried it but it does not work. @EstusFlask

Consider updating the question with your attempt

I have just added it. @EstusFlask

This could work. It's unknown what  i18n.global.locale.value is on server side

Neither the default locale nor locale param from route should be unknown on server side. @EstusFlask

I got it to work by creating these functions:
const qLangPacks = import.meta.glob(
  '../../node_modules/quasar/lang/(en-GB|es).js'
)

const qLocaleLangPacks = Object.entries(qLangPacks).map(([path, load]) => ({
  locale: path.slice(31, -3),
  load,
  path
}))

export async function qLoadLang(locale) {
  const [langLocale] = locale.split('-')

  const langPack = await qLocaleLangPacks
    .find((pack) => pack.locale === locale || pack.locale === langLocale)
    .load()

  return { ...langPack, isoName: locale }
}


Then simply call the function this way:
import { Lang } from 'Quasar'
(async () =>
  Lang.set(await qLoadLang(i18n.global.locale.value))
)()

Set this configuration:
// quasar.config.js
    framework: {
      config: {},

